# Create nested json from list of dicts and list of strings

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have 3 list of dicts and a list of strings that I need to convert into json format. TBH, I am not sure where to begin but if anyone can point me in the right direction, that will be super helpful

```
lst_strings = ['one', 'two']
d1 = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}]
d2 = [{'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}, {'d':7, 'e':8, 'f':9}]
d3 = [{'z': '0'}, {'g': 'false'}]
```

The json output I am looking for is formatted like this:

```
{
"one": [{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3",
    "two": [{
        "d": "4",
        "e": "5",
        "f": "6"
    }, {
        "d": "7",
        "e": "8",
        "f": "9"
    }],
    "z": "0"
}],
"g": false
```

}

What will be the best and most efficient way to achieve this result. I know I should post what I have done so far but honestly, my brain is dysfunctional at the moment.

Comment: It's completely unclear how your inputs relate to your output structure. Please explain the rules for transformation.

Comment: I will always have 2 strings in the first list. I will have to assign the first dict to the first string and the second string will be nested within the first string and it will contain all dicts in the 2nd list of dicts. The result is what's required. The format will never change. Only the contents of the 2nd list of dicts will ever change (increase or decrease)

Comment: You mean `'two'` is nested within the first dictionary? Then what about `d3`? Also, what exactly do you have problems with? Creating dictionaries?

Comment: 'two' is a sub of  'one' I think. I may be wrong but my exact problem is just converting the input to get the exact output I have there. Any manipulation that will give the exact result I posted should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json

lst_strings = ['one', 'two', 'three']
d1 = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}]
d2 = [{'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}, {'d':7, 'e':8, 'f':9}]
d3 = [{'z': '0'}, {'g': 'false'}]

d = {}
for i,s in enumerate(lst_strings):
    d[s] = eval(f'd{i+1}')

j = json.dumps(d)
print(j)
```

Output:

```
{"one": [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}], "two": [{"d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}, {"d": 7, "e": 8, "f": 9}], "three": [{"z": "0"}, {"g": "false"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, I maybe able to modify this. I will take a rest to clear my head and come back to it. Will upvote when I am done.